# As the temperature increases,the resistivity of conductor also increases why?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conductors

As the temperature increases, the resistivity of conductor also increases why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temperature dependence of resistivity in metals](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31406/)

Comment: what have you done to find out?